# Max Heap - samples In C

Tags: c

I want to display the binary tree as a Max Heap order.

Requirement
1) Input - Binary Tree
2) Output - Max Heap / Min Heap

Thanks a lot.

REgards,
Girija

Comment: Is this homework?  And what do you mean by "heap order"?

Comment: Do not dump your homework here. If you have a specific problem then you can ask for help here but don't ask us to give you a complete solution to something you should be doing.

Comment: THanks All. I solved the error in my code. It is works fine.

Comment: If it's solved, please vote up the interesting post and mark the best answer as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to use other's work:

[Use std::make_heap to make a heap from a vector](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/STL-Algorithms-Heap/Usestdmakeheaptocreateheapfromavector.htm)